# How to add image link as hyperlink to all images in content using preg_replace?

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to change the hyperlink of all images I post in content to image link. For now I can edit its link to anything using this

```
function add_image_responsive_class($content) {
   global $post;
   $pattern ="~<a .*?>\s*<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>\s*</a>~i";
   $replacement = '<a href="$1"><img$1class="$2"$3></a>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_image_responsive_class');
```

But I cant copy image link to hyperlink.

For example:

Now I have this:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage"><img src="imagelink"></a>
```

I want to change this to:

```
<a href="imagelink"><img src="imagelink"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there are a few ways you can do this.  I'll show you one easy way, but know that you can customize this down to a finer granularity.  The process will be the same, though.

Basically we're going to split up the string into chunks and save each chunk by putting a set of parenthesis around it.  We can then interchange chunks as we please.

Let's take your string and divide it up into different parts.

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage"><img src="imagelink"></a>
|---1---||---------------2-------------||-----3----||---4---||--5-|
```

Really what we want to do here is replace #2 with #4.  So the order would be:

```
#1 #4 #3 #4 #5
```

This is pretty easy to achieve with `preg_replace` and here's how:

```
$link_text = '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage"><img src="imagelink"></a>';

// JUST ADD PARENTHESIS AROUND EACH ITEM YOU WANT TO CAPTURE
$link_text = preg_replace('~(<a href=")(.*?)("><img src=")(.*?)("></a>)~i', '$1$4$3$4$5', $link_text);

print $link_text;
```

That give you the following:

```
<a href="imagelink"><img src="imagelink"></a>
```

That being said, you can really divide the string up however you wish ... doesn't have to be how I did it.  The concept would be the same.  Each set of parenthesis captures one item and gives it a number.  You can then plug in that number into any other part of the string.

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/49NH6V

Comment: That's not working... After adding `~(<a href=")(.*?)("><img src=")(.*?)("></a>)~i` in $pattern It shows blank page

Comment: Hmmm, I would probably have to see the page.  It works in the demo from what you said it should do, so unless your code is really different from your example, it should work.  Maybe the spacing is different or something.  Those things can be easily added to the expression and the concept would remain the same.